# How to construct my own ColorFunction with the TemperatureMap range

Tags: plotting, color

I would like to draw the unit circle and define my own coloring function on it so that every point $e^{i\theta}$ of the unit circle will be colored according to said function from the range of colors TemperatureMap.

For example, let's say I want to color every point on the unit circle according to a function (which I call "color"), in the following manner:

$color(e^{i\theta})=Sin(\theta)$

This means that the point $e^{i\theta}$ with the value $\theta$ such that $Sin(\theta)$ takes its greatest value, in this case $\theta=\pi/2$, will be the deepest red, and accordingly for the rest of the points.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @MarcoB Hah apologies I thought only the Math community wanted to see effort first! I've tried the regular stuff like ColorFunction->Function[{x,y},ColorData["TemperatureMap"][x]] 

But these options only play with the variables that your plot is already using. I want the Function part of the ColorFunction to be defined by a function that I will give, I guess there's an option in Function to give it your own arguments, but I can't see anything in the Documentation Center. 

I figured somebody who knows about RGB stuff could answer this on a whim.

Comment: Could you calculate the value of theta for each point using its $(x,y)$ coordinates within your custom color function, and then proceed with that? Perhaps `VectorAngle` could help you here.

Comment: Does `ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, -π, π}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, t}, ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {-1, 1}}, Sin[t]]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotStyle -> Thick]` suit your needs?

Comment: @J.M. Ah, beautiful, so for any of the custom ranges of mathematica, ColorData's second argument gives a range that I want my colors to take relative to the range of the function, and the third argument is the actual function I choose.

Thanks a lot! Why not post it as an answer I can accept?

Comment: Well, since you gave a very nice interpretation of the code I posted ;), I would prefer that you answer your own question with your explanation of my code. :) (I promise to upvote.) BTW: `ColorData[]` only takes two arguments. In your case, you needed a rescaling, so the first argument is a list containing the gradient name and the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[J. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m)'s comment-answer:

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, -π, π}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, t}, ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {-1, 1}}, Sin[t]]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.03]
]
```

[image]